# clustering of a text file

Tags: python, text, cluster-analysis

Original Question:
I have a flat file with each row representing text associated with an application. I would like to cluster applications based on the words associated with that application Is there a free code available for text mining a single flat file? Thank you.

Update 1:
There are 30,000 applications. I am trying to figure our what behaviors (of customers) are associated with each cluster. I dont have a pre defined set of words to start with. I could inspect a random few and determine some words, but then that would not give me a exaustive list of words. I would like to capture majority of the behaviors in a systematic way.

I tried converting the text file into an xml file and cluster using carrot2 workbench, but that didnt work. I havent used carrot2 before, so I may be doing something wrong there.

Comment: need more details on how you want the files to be clustered.

Comment: If you could define 'cluster applications', especially in the context of clustering them by the 'words' they are associated with, that would prove helpful.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789254/clustering-text-in-python

Comment: Carrot2 is good for clustering based on the text of your items, try this to get started: http://doc.carrot2.org/#section.getting-started.xml-files. For large data sets (>1000 items), use Carrot2's STC clustering algorithm; for smaller sets, stick with the Lingo algorithm. For clustering based on numerical attributes, take a look at Apache Mahout project.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your have a file like:

```
game Solitaire
productivity OpenOffice
game MineSweeper
...
```

And you want to categorize everything based on their tag word, as in putting applications in buckets based on their associated tag/description/...

I think you can use a dictionary of lists for this purpose, e.g.:

```
f = open('input.txt')
out = {}
inline = f.readline()
while inline:
    if ' ' not in inline:
        continue
    tag, appname = inline.strip('\n').split(' ', 1)
    if tag not in out:
        out[tag] = []
    out[tag].append(appname)
    inline = f.readline()

print out['game']
```

This iterates through input once and clusters application names based on their tags very efficiently.