# Python Elasticsearch and Carrot

Tags: elasticsearch, carrot2, pyelasticsearch

I am using python elastic search and I need to do document clustering. I have installed carrot2 ( https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2 ).

How do I call the carrot clustering module from python after

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.search(.....)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrot2 plugin for ES will give you access to the clustered documents at

> ```
> http://localhost:9200/_plugin/carrot2/ (or wherever your ES node is deployed)
> ```

Look at the [usage guide](https://github.com/carrot2/elasticsearch-carrot2#usage-guide) in the github project page.

There is no support for carrot2 cluster access from pyelasticsearch. You can apply carrot2 on top of the search results from pyelasticsearch. Take a look at the [carrot2 project](https://github.com/carrot2/carrot2) if you need to use carrot2. Else take a look at some python text clustering tools [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789254/clustering-text-in-python).

Comment: How do I apply carrot2 on top of search results from pyelasticsearch?

Comment: You will have to build carrot2 clustering as a service and call it from your python project. Any particular reason why you cannot use existing python clustering tools?

Comment: Existing python clustering tools do not take care about the knowledge of the universe. I want to cluster 10 documents into n clusters, using the information of 1000000 documents. I guess carrot2 is the way to go.

Comment: Can you please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540328/carrot2elasticsearch-basic-flow-of-information

Comment: Yes, you can move away from pyelasticsearch if you want to use the plugin. REST is the way to go. Will reply on the thread.

Comment: @PratikPoddar Are you able to solve the carrot2 call using python? I also needed to use carrot2 making rest call to it. Can you please guide